# atan2f precision on xcode

Tags: c++, math

I have this very simple code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("%2.21f", atan2f(0.f, -1.f));

    return 0;
}
```

With next output on Intel CPUs:

```
Visual Studio 2010: 3.141592741012573200000
GCC 4.8.1         : 3.141592741012573242188
Xcode 5           : 3.141592502593994140625
```

After reading Appple manual pages for atan2f, I expect the printed value to be near `3.14159265359`, as they say they will return `+pi` for special values like the one I'm using now. As you can see the difference is quite big from the value returned on Xcode and expected value.

Is this a know issue? If yes, is there any workaround to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single-precision floating point number has only about 7 digits of decimal precision.  Your test value of `3.14159265359` has 12.  If you want better precision, use `double` or `long double` and `atan2` or `atan2l` to match.

Likely the reason you're getting "better" results from VS and GCC is that the compiler is noticing your function has constant arguments and is precalculating the result at higher-than-single precision.  Check the generated code for proof.

Comment: I'm making the tests in debug mode. In asm code there is a call to atan2f() functions on all platforms.

Comment: So does `atan2f` on VS and/or GCC convert up to higher precision numbers?

Comment: The correct digits in the results are `3.141592`. The digits after that in all three approximations are wrong; they are an artifact of floating-point representation.

Comment: I checked the assembly generated by Visual Studio and the call goes to atan2 with higher precision arguments(http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH14/CH14-4.html#HEADING4-5)

Answer (score 1):

The knee-jerk workaround is to use `atan2`. Casting that down to `float` gave me `3.141592741012573242188` just like your GCC 4.8.1 test.

I would assume `atan2f` gives an answer not quite as precise as a `float` could hold because it arrives at its answer by some means that means that estimating the output precision is a smarter way to go.